# version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found on Gentoo

Tags: gcc, libstdc++, gentoo, engineyard

I've updated my gem file of `wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge` into `0.12.5` and when I try to export to pdf in my gentoo machine (Working with EngineYard) I get the following error:

> /data/frontend/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge-0.12.5.0/libexec/wkhtmltopdf-linux-amd64:
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.4/libstdc++.so.6: version
>   `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by
>   /data/frontend/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge-0.12.5.0/libexec/wkhtmltopdf-linux-amd64)
>   /data/frontend/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge-0.12.5.0/libexec/wkhtmltopdf-linux-amd64:
>   /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required
>   by
>   /data/frontend/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge-0.12.5.0/libexec/wkhtmltopdf-linux-amd64)
>   /data/frontend/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge-0.12.5.0/libexec/wkhtmltopdf-linux-amd64:
>   /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available
>   (required by
>   /data/frontend/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/2.3.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge-0.12.5.0/libexec/wkhtmltopdf-linux-amd64)

My gcc version is:

```
gcc (Gentoo Hardened 4.5.4-r1 p1.0, pie-0.4.7) 4.5.4
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Just a couple questions: Have you tried 0.12.3? What stack version are you running on Engine Yard? I ask because we're using 0.12.3 on stable-v4 and it works.